# How to identify the updated files in the destination folder on running XCOPY?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have created a batch file to synchronize the updated files from a source folder to destination folder. It is working perfectly. Now I want to identify (or copy to folder) the updated files in the destination folder each time when I run the script, so that it could be used for some operations.

Is there a way to achieve this?

**xcopy.bat**

```
xcopy E:\sss q:  /c /d /e /h /i /k /q /r /s /y
```

Comment: Examine the `/L` switch. you'd probably need `echo y|xcopy /L ... >sonereportfile`

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit .

Comment: The `/L` switch on `xcopy` lists the files that would be copied. It waits for a user-input to authorise the `xcopy`, hence `echo`ing `y` into the `xcopy` command will start without bothering the user. The redirector will redirect the output of the command to the file nominated. All explained in the `xcopy` documentation (`xcopy /?` from the prompt)

Comment: Removing the `/Q` switch should cause `xcopy` to display all files that are copied; and check out the `/F` option to get the destination paths too; you can then capture the output by a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)...

Comment: @aschipfl It would be really helpful if you could provide an example code

Comment: @NewCoder If you really have named your batch file `xcopy.bat` containing the command `xcopy` without full path and file extension, then `xcopy.bat` runs on execution of command `xcopy` itself once again. Never give a batch file the name of an internal command of Windows command interpreter or of an existing executable like `xcopy.exe` in Windows system directory. You know now why I am referencing in batch files always executables in Windows system directory with full path and with file extension to avoid a not working batch file because of bad file names or bad `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Remove in target directory `Q:\` recursive the archive attribute from all files in all directories before running the **XCOPY** command. Then run **XCOPY** for copying all newer files to `Q:\`. Last process all files with archive attribute set in target directory which are the files copied by **XCOPY**.

Example batch file just printing into console window the files with archive attribute set after copying newer files:

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -A Q:\* /S
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe E:\sss Q:\ /C /D /E /H /I /K /Q /R /S /Y >nul
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir Q:\* /AA-D /B /S 2^>nul') do echo %%I
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `attrib /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `xcopy /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: So after copying all the old files in the destination folder will be set to Archive? When I run the above script I couldn't see anything except that the copy was working

Comment: @NewCoder Do you know what all the switches on __XCOPY__ command are for? `/D` without a date means copying only those files from `E:\sss` to ``Q:\`` which are newer in `E:\sss` than in ``Q:\`` or do not exist in ``Q:\`` at all. So it is possible that nothing is copied and therefore no file in ``Q:\`` has the archive attribute set. I prefer the `/M` switch, but you have posted the __XCOPY__ command line. I tested the batch file before posting and it worked as expected on my computer.

Comment: Yes. I did read the xcopy documentation. Now it copies the newer/modified from 'E:\sss' to 'Q:\'. What I'm trying to do here is to identify this copied newer/modified files each time i run the script so that I can update  my application folder only with these new files.

Comment: @NewCoder And the __FOR__ loop outputs all files with full path having archive attribute set because of file was copied by __XCOPY__ just before. What is `Q:`? I suppose this is a network share mapped to drive letter `Q:` with a Windows file system (FAT32, NTFS). If `Q:` is a Unix/Linux file system mounted via Samba, this method would not work as Unix/Linux file systems do not support archive attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To list all the files that have actually been copied you could replace switch `/Q` (do not display file names) by `/F` (display full source and destination file names) and extract the destination paths from the output, like in the following example (see all the explanatory comments):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=E:\sss" & rem // (path to source directory)
set "_TARGET=Q:\\"   & rem // (path to destination directory)

rem /* Run `xcopy` to do its job (remove `/L` to actually copy files); the `/F` option
rem    lets `xcopy` output the full source and destination paths of each file copied,
rem    separated from each other by ` -> `; hence split each line at this separator to
rem    extract the destination path; `find` filters out the final summary line (like
rem    `?? File(s)`); `for /F` finally captures the output of `xcopy`: */
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    xcopy "%_SOURCE%" "%_TARGET%" /C /D /E /H /I /K /F /R /Y /L ^| find ">"
') do (
    rem // Store current line (source and destination paths) in variable:
    set "FILE=%%F"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with exclamation marks:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Split current line at said separator to retrieve the destination path:
    set "FILE=!FILE:* -> =!"
    rem // Return the extracted destination path:
    echo/!FILE!
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Do not forget to remove the `/L` (list files that would be copied) option from `xcopy` to actually copy any files.

If you want the list of files to be written into a text file (like `filelist.txt` in the directory of the batch file, for example), use the following code (leaving out most comments this time):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=E:\sss" & rem // (path to source directory)
set "_TARGET=Q:\\"   & rem // (path to destination directory)
set "_LISTFILE=%~dp0filelist.txt" & rem // (path to list file)

rem // Redirect output of whole `for /F` loop to a text file:
> "%_LISTFILE%" (
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
        xcopy "%_SOURCE%" "%_TARGET%" /C /D /E /H /I /K /F /R /Y /L ^| find ">"
    ') do (
        set "FILE=%%F"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "FILE=!FILE:* -> =!"
        echo/!FILE!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: It is showing invalid number of parameters in the xcopy command line also `'')' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`

Comment: I cannot reproduce any of these two errors, so I recommend to copy the script once again; I only removed the trailing `\ `from the source path to prevent `xcopy` from returning an `Invalid path` error...

Comment: I have pasted the above script into a text editor and saved it as a script.bat file. Then running it as administrator. Are you doing it in some other way ?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it the same way, so I don't get why it fails for you... Is it a text encoding problem? (it must be an ASCII/ANSI text file, with Windows-style line-breaks; that's why I'm using `notepad.exe`)